# Simple authentication without user login

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

What is the ideal way for a mobile app which authenticates to a Laravel API without user login but needs to detect an app user for example filtering for favorites? Should we use Personal Access Tokens?
We used it in combination with a dummy user for each. But now we experience issues with the expiration of Personal Access Tokens which are only 1 year valid. Is there a better approach?

Thank you very much

Comment: You could just set an insanely long Expiry on your tokens: `Passport::tokensExpireIn(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->addYears(100));` See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#configuration for what I mean

Answer (score 0):

You can use JWT with https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth and if you need get the user you only need send the token in the header.

example :

```
Authorization : 'bearer TOKEN'
```

example if you need take user :

```
use JWTAuth;

public function index(Request $request)
{
  $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();

}
```

I do not know if it's the best way, but I like it and it's easy to use

I hope I help you